# Visual solution of the Newtonial differential equation with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, physics

I wrote this Python code that plots the movement of an object under the effect of a given force function in 2D by solving the Newton's movement equation numerically. One can add other force functions, or even parameters to the draw_path function. I tried to make it as readable as I could. 
I would really appreciate if you could tell me what did I wrong, and what would have you done diferently.

*Since I learned programming only by tutorials and codes, never from proper lessons/courses, and this is my first finished code, I probably did some weird things. Since I am not a native speaker, I probably wrote some weird comments. Sorry.*

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#  movement_equation_2.0.py
#
#  Copyright 2016 Nagy Gergely
#
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#  :Author: Nagy Gergely
#  :Version: 0.2.1 beta
#  :Status: Prototype
#  :Date: 2016.01.05





"Non-physics functions"

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

#dimensions for vectors
x = 0
y = 1

def plot_base(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax):
    """
    Creates a base for the plot: a white picture with two orthogonal lines, the x
    and y axis, according to the given minimum and maximum coordinates in pixels.
    """
    base_color = 'white'
    axis_color = 'grey'

    xsize = abs(xmax - xmin)
    ysize = abs(ymax - ymin)
    plot = Image.new('RGB', (xsize, ysize), base_color)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(plot)

    #draw x axis if shown:
    if ymin < 0 and ymax > 0:
        draw.line((0, ymax, xsize, ymax), axis_color)
    elif ymax > 0:
        draw.line((0, ysize, xsize, ysize), axis_color)
    else:
        draw.line((0, 0, xsize, 0), axis_color)

    #draw y axis if shown:
    if xmin < 0 and xmax > 0:
        draw.line((0-xmin, 0, 0-xmin, ysize), axis_color)
    elif xmax > 0:
        draw.line((0, 0, 0, ysize),axis_color)
    else:
        draw.line((xsize, 0, xsize, ysize),axis_color)

    return plot


def draw_path(m, r0, v0, force_function, time, dt, plot_size, resolution):
    """
    Draws the path of an object with weight m starting from r0 with velocity v0,
    according to the force function given in the force_function method.

    :param m: the mass of the object
    :param r0: the coordinates of the object at t=0 in meters (2-tuple)
    :param v0: the coordinates of the initial velocity vector (2-tuple)
    :param force_function: the function of the force applied to the object, described below
    :param time: the time of the movement
    :param dt: time elapsed ed between two calculated point: the bigger it is, the faster but less accurate is the result
    :param plot_size: the minimum and the maximum x and y coordinates as a 4-tuple: (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
    :param resolution: resolution of the result plot image (meter/pixel)
    """
    trace_color = (255, 0, 0)
    plot_pixsize = [int(i/resolution) for i in plot_size]
    plot = plot_base(*plot_pixsize)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(plot)
    m = float(m)
    r = (float(r0[x]), float(r0[y]))
    v = (float(v0[x]), float(v0[y]))

    i = 0
    pos, prev_pos = None, None
    while float(i)*dt < time:

        #physics calculations
        F = force_function(m=m, r=r, v=v)
        a = (F[x]/m                        , F[y]/m                       )
        v = (v[x] + a[x]*dt                , v[y] + a[y]*dt               )
        r = (r[x] + v[x]*dt + a[x]/2*dt**2 , r[y] + v[y]*dt + a[y]/2*dt**2)

        #drawing the line between the current and the previous position if both is on the plot
        pix_pos_x = round(r[x]/resolution) - plot_pixsize[0]
        pix_pos_y = round(r[y]/resolution) *-1 + plot_pixsize[3]
        if ((0 < pix_pos_x < plot_pixsize[1]-plot_pixsize[0]) and
            (0 < pix_pos_y < plot_pixsize[3]-plot_pixsize[2])):
            pos = pix_pos_x, pix_pos_y
        else:
            pos = None

        if pos is not None and prev_pos is not None:
            draw.line((prev_pos, pos), fill=trace_color)
            #plot.putpixel((pix_pos_x, pix_pos_y), trace_color)     #'dotty' but may visualize speed

        prev_pos=pos
        i += 1

    return plot



"""
*******************************************************************************
FORCE FUNCTIONS
*******************************************************************************
"""



import math

"physics constants"

_c_  = 299792458 # m/s                  speed of light
_y_  = 6.67384 * (10**-11) # Nm²/kg²    gravitational constant
_h_  = 6.62606957 * (10**-34) # Js      Planck's constant
_E0_ = 8.854187817 * (10**-12) # C²/Nm² electric constant
_u0_ = 4.0 * math.pi # Tm/A             magnetic constant
_g_  = 9.80665 # m/s²                   standard gravity
_e_  = 1.602176565 * (10**-19) # C      elementary charge
_me_ = 9.10938291 * 10**-31 # kg        mass of electron
_mp_ = 1.672621777 * 10**-27 #kg        mass of proton
_Na_ = 6.02214129 * 10**23 #1/mol       Avogadro's constant

_Me_  = 5.972 * 10**24 # kg             mass of the Earth
_Ms_  = 1.989 * 10**30 # kg             mass of the Sun
_Mm_  = 7.34767309 * 10**22 #kg         mass of the Moon


"""
Force functions for the movement plotter. They should take the paramaters as keyword
arguments (use **kwargs to be compatible with more parameters in the future), and
return the coordinates of the force vector at these parameters as a 2-tuple.
Possible variablesat the moment: m, r, v
"""

def r_xy_dep(**variables):
    """force depends on the x and the y coordinates"""
    r = variables['r']
    F = [0.0 , -1.0]

    F[x] = 0
    F[y] = _g_*F[y]

    return F


def v_xy_dep(**variables):
    """force depends on the x and the y velocity"""
    v = variables('v')
    F = [0.0 , 1.0]
    F[x] = -(v[x]**2) * v[x]/abs(v[x])
    F[y] = -(v[y]**2) * v[y]/abs(v[y])

    return F


def central(**variables):
    """central force field, force depends on the
       vector from the centrum to the object"""

    r0 = variables['r']
    c = (0.0 , 0.0)               # centrum
    r = (r0[x]-c[x] , r0[y]-c[y]) # vector from centrum to r0
    r_ = math.hypot(r[x], r[y])   # length of r
    fi = math.atan2(r[y], r[x])   # angle of r

    F_ = -r_                      #force dependency
    dfi = 0                       #the angle between the force vector and r

    F_x = F_*math.cos(fi+dfi)
    F_y = F_*math.sin(fi+dfi)
    return (F_x, F_y)

def gravitational(**variables):
    #(special type of central dependency)

    central_mass = _Me_   # mass of the scource object
    m = variables['m']
    r0 = variables['r']
    c = (0.0 , 0.0)
    r = (r0[x]-c[x] , r0[y]-c[y])
    r_ = math.hypot(r[x], r[y])
    fi = math.atan2(r[y], r[x])
    F_ = -r_
    F_x = F_*math.cos(fi+dfi)
    F_y = F_*math.sin(fi+dfi)
    return (F_x, F_y)

def v_dep(**variables):
    """force depends on the velocity vector
       (i.e. charged particle in magnetic field)"""
    v_xy = variables['v']
    v_ = math.hypot(v_xy[x], v_xy[y])
    fi = math.atan2(v_xy[y], v_xy[x])

    F_ = v_
    dfi = math.pi/2

    F_x = F_*math.cos(fi+dfi)
    F_y = F_*math.sin(fi+dfi)
    return (F_x, F_y)



"""
******************************************************************************
MAIN MOVEMENT DRAWER FUNCTION
******************************************************************************
"""

def main(arg):

    m = 0.1               #mass of the object in kilograms
    r0 = (0, 0)           #initial coordinates in meters
    v0 = (30, 0)          #initial velocity vector in m/s
    dependency = v_dep    #force function from above
    time = 10             #time of movement to draw in secs
    time_res = 1/70000    #time between steps in secs, determines accuracy and running time
    plot_size = (-10, 10, -10, 10)  #minimum and maximum coordinates in meters (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
    plot_res = 0.01       #meters per pixel on the plot

    plot = draw_path(m, r0, v0, dependency, time, time_res, plot_size, plot_res)
    plot.show()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Also on Github: https://gist.github.com/godot11/998e71fca8f8f4fce1a1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is pretty good work for a self-taught programmer.  I'd like to make a few suggestions to improve readability.

---

First, I would **define a 2D vector class**.  That would allow you to simplify expressions where you are doing the same operation to both the *x* and the *y* coordinate, such as `r = (r[x] + v[x]*dt + a[x]/2*dt**2 , r[y] + v[y]*dt + a[y]/2*dt**2)`, into

```
r += (v * dt) + (a * dt**2 / 2)
```

To achieve that, I would use `namedtuple`, so that you can have `vec.x` and `vec.y` members instead of `vec[x]` and `vec[y]`.

```
from collections import namedtuple
import math
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

class Vec2(namedtuple('Vec2', 'x y')):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Vec2(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Vec2(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)

    def __mul__(self, scale):
        return Vec2(self.x * scale, self.y * scale)

    def __truediv__(self, scale):
        return Vec2(self.x / scale, self.y / scale)

    def rotate(self, angle):
        sin, cos = math.sin(angle), math.cos(angle)
        return Vec2(self.x * cos - self.y * sin, self.x * sin + self.y * cos)
```

The `Vec2` class would also let the code express your mathematical intentions — for example, your entire eight-line `v_dep()` function could be written as…

```
###############################################################################
# FORCE FUNCTIONS
###############################################################################
# Force functions for the movement plotter. They should take the paramaters as
# keyword arguments (use **kwargs to be compatible with more parameters in the
# future), and return the coordinates of the force vector at these parameters
# as a 2-tuple.  Possible variables at the moment: m, r, v
###############################################################################

def v_dep(**variables):
    """force depends on the velocity vector
       (i.e. charged particle in magnetic field)"""
    return variables['v'].rotate(math.pi / 2)
```

---

The other change would be to **disentangle the physics from the plotting**.  In particular, I'd prefer not to have code like `pix_pos_x = round(r[x]/resolution) - plot_pixsize[0]` in your `draw_path` loop, which is already complicated as it is.

I suggest defining a `Canvas` class to contain the image, the bounds information, and handle the physical-to-pixel coordinate translation.

```
class Canvas:
    def __init__(self, bounds, resolution, base_color='white'):
        """
        :param bounds: positions of the upper-left and lower-right corners, each as a Vec2
        :param resolution: resolution of the result plot image (meter/pixel)
        """
        self._nw_corner, self._se_corner = bounds
        self._resolution = resolution

        width = round((self._se_corner.x - self._nw_corner.x) / resolution)
        height = round((self._nw_corner.y - self._se_corner.y) / resolution)
        self._plot = Image.new('RGB', (width, height), base_color)
        self._draw = ImageDraw.Draw(self._plot)

        self._pos = None
        self.color = 'black'

    def draw_axes(self, axis_color='grey'):
        #draw x axis
        self._draw.line([
            self._phys_to_draw(Vec2(self._nw_corner.x, 0)),
            self._phys_to_draw(Vec2(self._se_corner.x, 0))
        ], axis_color)

        #draw y axis
        self._draw.line([
            self._phys_to_draw(Vec2(0, self._nw_corner.y)),
            self._phys_to_draw(Vec2(0, self._se_corner.y))
        ], axis_color)

    def draw_to(self, r):
        """Draw a line from the previous position (if any) to the specified position"""
        self._prev_pos, self._pos = self._pos, self._phys_to_draw(r)
        if self._prev_pos is not None:
            self._draw.line((self._prev_pos, self._pos), fill=self.color)

    def show(self):
        self._plot.show()

    def _phys_to_draw(self, r):
        """Translate physical coordinates to image coordinates"""
        return (
            round((r.x - self._nw_corner.x) / self._resolution),
            round((self._nw_corner.y - r.y) / self._resolution)
        )
```

---

Here's the rest of the code:

```
def draw_path(canvas, m, r0, v0, force_function, duration, dt):
    """
    Draws the path of an object with weight m starting from r0 with velocity v0,
    according to the force function given in the force_function method.

    :param m: the mass of the object
    :param r0: the coordinates of the object at t=0 in meters (2-tuple)
    :param v0: the coordinates of the initial velocity vector (2-tuple)
    :param force_function: the function of the force applied to the object, described below
    :param duration: the duration of the movement
    :param dt: time elapsed between two calculated points: the bigger it is, the faster but less accurate is the result
    """
    r = r0
    v = v0

    canvas.color = (255, 0, 0)
    canvas.draw_to(r)
    for _ in range(int(duration / dt)):
        F = force_function(m=m, r=r, v=v)
        a = F / m
        v += a * dt
        r += (v * dt) + (a * dt**2 / 2)
        canvas.draw_to(r)




###############################################################################
# MAIN MOVEMENT DRAWER FUNCTION
###############################################################################

def main(arg):
    canvas = Canvas(
        bounds=(Vec2(-10, 10), Vec2(10, -10)),
        resolution=0.01,                #meters per pixel on the plot
    )
    canvas.draw_axes()
    draw_path(
        canvas=canvas,
        m=0.1,                          #mass of the object in kilograms
        r0=Vec2(0, 0),                  #initial coordinates in meters
        v0=Vec2(30, 0),                 #initial velocity vector in m/s
        force_function=v_dep,           #force function from above
        duration=10,                    #time of movement to draw in secs
        dt=1/70000,                     #time between steps in secs, determines accuracy and running time
    )
    canvas.show()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

---

Additional remarks:

- Avoid using `"""strings"""` as comments.  Either write proper `"""docstrings"""` on functions, or write `# comments`.
- Numbers like `6.67384 * (10**-11)` are better written as `6.67384e-11`.
- Counting loops like…

  > ```
  > i = 0
  > while …:
  >     …
  >     i += 1
  > ```

  … are better written using `for i in range(…): …`.
- By moving the creation of the image and axes out of `draw_path()`, we can allow for multiple particles to be drawn on the same canvas.
- `draw_path()` takes a lot of parameters.  Using named parameters makes the code clearer and less susceptible to parameter mismatches.
- Don't worry about drawing out of bounds.  Let the PIL library crop the image for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the review! You clearly spent time with it, and I learned a lot of things from it.

Comment: There's a simpler way to implement `rotate`, using only two trig calls: `x, y = self; s, c = sin(theta), cos(theta); return Vec2(x * c - y * s, x * s + y * c)`

Comment: @GarethRees Incorporated in Rev 3. Thanks.